# How to Approve spend of one or many Token with Web3.js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

I am currently using an html page (with javascript) that is available to my users. I need to set up a button that allows the spending of BUSD or other stablecoin tokens on the same page.

Once the button is clicked I want Metamask to open and ask the user if they want to approve the address (for example: 0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56) for the token spending.

I found an approach that works well for connecting and loading the wallet. BUT the transaction for the approve function does not work. Here is my code, i added the complete JS and the complete HTML:

I entirely reworked my code, but only Metasmask show up for the connection and not for the transaction.

**Javascript**:

```
async function approve() {
const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');
const contractadress = 0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56
const howMuchTokentoApprove = 100
const senderAddress = 0x9e737ea674A3C941FE9C84C30C03578675B69b4c
await window.web3.currentProvider.enable();

 var abi = [ {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          { "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" },
          { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" },
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function",
      },];
    try {
        var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractadress);

        var nonceResponse = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress); 
        var nonce = nonceResponse;
        var txParams = {
            gas: web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
            chainId: chainId,
            to: contractadress
        };

        
        txParams.data = await contract.methods.approve(senderAddress,
                                howMuchTokentoApprove).encodeABI();

        var signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txParams, process.env.senderPrivateKey);
        nonce += 1;
        txParams.nonce = web3.utils.toHex(nonce);
        await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
        console.log("Token spending approved. \n");
        txAlreadyApprove = true;
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('err', error);

    }
  
}
```

**HTML** :

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/busd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ethers-v4.min.js"></script>


</head>

<button class="btn-default margin-t3" type="button" onclick="approve()">Approve</button>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does `approve` do?

Comment: The function approves the spending of the user's tokens.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't provided enough details to try reproducing the error. The only thing I see is that you are calling approve with a 0 value, where it usually is the amount you want to approve.

Comment: Sorry but, i didn't have any errors. Metamask opens, but no transaction or request form appears.

Comment: I just added my complete code HTML + JS. I got the same problem. Metamask start just for connect to the site. But he doesn't want launch an approve transaction.

Comment: The code doesn't use metamask at all, it is signing the transaction by itself. To connect with metamask use the official guide https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html. The you should initialize the web3 object with metamask `window.ethereum` provider.